# Node doesn't start without source ~/.bash_profile command

Tags: node.js, nvm, zshrc

I have to use `source ~/.bash_profile` for node command to work on my terminal. All the node commands work just fine after using `source ~/.bash_profile`. I used nvm to install Node LTS(v14.18.0).

My .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Is there any way to fix my node installation?

Comment: Did you try running [`nvm alias`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#set-default-node-version) already? (and remember that this is for new shells, so quit your terminal and start a new one after issuing that command)

Comment: Just noticed that nvm commands also don't work without using `source ~/.bash_profile`.
No I don't remember using `nvm use`.

Comment: then it sounds like you want to return to the source and copy-paste the bit at the end of https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script first. And then rather than sourcing, quitting and starting a new terminal, just to rule out any source-related issues (which are about as unlikely as anything, but restarting a terminal is hardly a chore. Arguably faster than typing `source`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS uses zsh as the default shell and not bash. You will need to create a ~/.zshrc file and then run the install script of nvm again.

You can probably skip the rerunning the install script by manually inserting in .zshrc file the following:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

"*Since macOS 10.15, the default shell is zsh and nvm will look for .zshrc to update, none is installed by default. Create one with touch ~/.zshrc and run the install script again.*" - from nvm docs on github.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue. I used the following code on .zshrc, both node and nvm are working fine.
`export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and the above solution didn't work for me.
Finally the solution that did work for me was adding these lines to `~/.zshrc` file.

`source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Comment: This is a much simpler solution. I am using macOS Ventura.